# Android Studio auto suggestion and auto complete not working

Tags: java, android-studio

When I type Edit for EditText it doesn't show nothing
but it works fine with XML

[image]

I tried disabling power save mod but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error in the image, you need to import the button class. To import the button class, write the following code at the top after the package statement:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

You also need to define the Button variable outside the onCreate function inside the MainActivity class.

To solve the problem of auto complete:

1. First close Android Studio
2. Go to C:/Users/your_user_name/.AndroidStudio/system/
3. Delete the cache folder
4. Start Android Studio again

Comment: it didn't work for me